# Extract nth substring

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, substr

I need to extract a sub string from a string. Given below are the IDs that are available.

0234-RDRT-**RS111**-M-EU

0234-RDRT-**RSD123**-M-EU

I need to extract the highlighted ones to a column. How do I extract all the characters to the same column in Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: just edited the query.

Comment: Are the data always located after the second dash ?

Comment: yes, i need to extract all the data that is available after every dash in different columns.

Comment: As your looking for constants why not `like '%-%-RSD123-%-%'`

Comment: @AlexK. That might work if there are always a fixed number of delimited strings but if the input could be `111-222-333-RDS123-555-666` then it will match it even though it is matching the 4th delimited item and not the 3rd as expected.

Answer (score 4):

The fourth parameter of `REGEX_SUBSTR` is the called `occurence`. You just have to set the occurence you want to see for each column:

```
CREATE TABLE T (id varchar2(30));
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('0234-RDRT-RS111-M-EU');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('0234-RDRT-RSD123-M-EU');

SELECT regexp_substr(id,'[^-]+',1,1) as col1,
       regexp_substr(id,'[^-]+',1,2) as col2,
       regexp_substr(id,'[^-]+',1,3) as col3,
       regexp_substr(id,'[^-]+',1,4) as col4,
       regexp_substr(id,'[^-]+',1,5) as col5
  FROM t;

COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4    COL5
0234    RDRT    RS111   M   EU
0234    RDRT    RSD123  M   EU
```

See [`REGEX_SUBSTR`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions164.htm#SQLRF06303) in Oracle's documentation for more details.

Comment: Thank you. How do i specify the number of characters i want in this expression?

Comment: You're welcome. You normally specify the kind of character, not the number. `[]` is a set of characters, `^-` means anything but a minus, and the `+` means one or more. You can indeed specify the numbers with something like '[0-9]{3,5}' which means 3 to 5 digits, or `[A-Z0-9]{2,6}` which means between 2 and 6 letters or digits, etc, etc. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_posix.htm#SQLRF020) for the full list.

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thankyou for your support. I was able to get the data that i needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract all the values of your column `id` by spliting them on the dash

```
select regexp_substr(id,'[^-]+', 1, level) 
from (select '0234-RDRT-RSD123-M-EU' as id 
        from dual)
connect by regexp_substr(id, '[^-]+', 1, level) is not null
```

the result has 5 lines.
You can then exploit the result as needed

Answer (score -2):

Split based on '-' , store in string array  then take 3rd element .

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. If you want to improve it then please show a complete code snippet that will work in Oracle SQL (which is what the question is tagged with).